# Java - sending HTTP parameters with apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x, arrays

i am trying to send `application/json` data using httpclient also i want to send some parameter with http post.

How to do this when using `apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost`.

Please can some one help me on this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can send post parameters *and* JSON at the same time, since the JSON string already will be the content of the request body. You could try sending the query parameters as part of the URL, and create a regular `StringEntity` for your JSON:

```
String jsonString = createMyJsonString();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlWithQueryParams);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString,"UTF-8"));
```

If you're posting to a REST service, it's common to include the parameters identifying the resource in the URL path. So if you have control over the end point, you could consider making the POST url independent of query/post parameters.

Comment: The method is wrapped with this annotations `@RequestBody` that is the reason why i don't have to specify the query params in the url. Sorry for the late reply. Please help